# Print list to console separated by newlines

Tags: print

I'm trying to run `emacsclient -e` with an expression that evaluates to a string containing newlines, and I'd like those newlines to be rendered on the console as newlines rather than `\n`.

Unfortunately, every attempt I've made so far prints the escaped newline:

```
$ emacsclient -e '(string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "\n")'
"a\nb\nc"
$ emacsclient -e '(print (string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "\n"))'
"a\nb\nc"
$ emacsclient -e '(message (string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "\n"))'
"a\nb\nc"
$ emacsclient -e '(string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "
> "))'
"a\nb\nc"
```

What am I missing? Bonus points if the quotation marks can also be removed from the output. Intended output:

```
$ emacsclient -e '(somefunction (list "a" "b" "c"))'
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use other tool to interpret the string, such as `echo`

```
bash-4.4$ emacsclient --eval '"hello\nworld"' | xargs echo -e
hello
world
bash-4.4$
```

Another way is to change what the server will return, by default, the
server will returns a `pp` representation of a Lisp value, with the
following advice, for Strings, it use a `princ` representation

```
(define-advice server-eval-and-print (:override (expr proc) render-string)
  (let ((v (with-local-quit (eval (car (read-from-string expr))))))
    (when proc
      (with-temp-buffer
        (let ((standard-output (current-buffer)))
          (if (stringp v)
              (princ v)
            (pp v))
          (let ((text (buffer-substring-no-properties
                       (point-min) (point-max))))
            (server-reply-print (server-quote-arg text) proc)))))))

;; To uninstall (i.e., remove the advice)
;; (advice-remove 'server-eval-and-print #'server-eval-and-print@render-string)
```

Give it a try

```
bash-4.4$ emacsclient --eval '"hello\nworld"'
hello
world
bash-4.4$
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--batch` argument can be used. From [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html):

> The command-line option ‘-batch’ causes Emacs to run noninteractively.
>   In this mode, Emacs does not read commands from the terminal, it does
>   not alter the terminal modes, and it does not expect to be outputting
>   to an erasable screen.

Later, it discusses output:

> Any Lisp program output that would normally go to the echo area, either using message, or using prin1, etc., with t as the stream, goes instead to Emacs's standard descriptors when in batch mode: message writes to the standard error descriptor, while prin1 and other print functions write to the standard output.

So we can call `emacs` with the `--batch` and `-eval form` arguments:

```
$ emacs --batch --eval '(progn (require (quote subr-x)) (message (string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "\n")))'
a
b
c
```

Note that `--batch` prevents your init file from being loaded. Therefore, because we're using `string-join`, we have to `require` the library containing it (`subr-x`) before using it. You could, alternately, use `-l <file>` to load your init file, before using `--eval <lisp code>` on the code you want to actually print.

Comment: Or just `(message (mapconcat (quote identity) (list "a" "b" "c") "\n"))`. However, `emacsclient` does not have a `--batch` option.

Comment: Why do you want to use emacsclient instead of emacs?

Comment: Because I want to operate on information in the server.

Comment: The `emacsclient` call is not showing you the messages printed, but instead the return value of the s-expression being evaled. I'm unsure how to connect to an existing server and print out things to the console.

Answer (score 0):

This is moderately horrible, but maybe just pipe it through something in the shell to deal with translating the `\n` into an actual newline?

Proof-of-concept:

```
% emacsclient -e '(message (string-join (list "a" "b" "c") "\n"))' | perl -e 'print eval <>'
a
b
c
```

(I feel like I should put some sort of "I would never normally do this, but..." disclaimer on that bit of Perl...)